# How to accept, store and sort the values in while loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I want to accept input from a user and store them in the
 empty list and sort that values and then print it but I'm getting
 last value printed.

```
sort_value = [].sort(key=int)
chances = 1

while chances <= 5:
    a = int(input("Enter a number"))
    if a >= 0:
        sort_value = a
        chances += 1
print(sort_value)
```

Comment: Sort *after* the loop. `.sort()` only sorts the list when it is called. Also, you're not using it correctly (look at some examples on Google).

Comment: It says '' TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable "

Comment: That happens if you try to iterate (or sort) over an `int` rather than a `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort_value = [].sort()` will assign `None` to `sort_value` since `sort()` doesn't have `return` statement.

`sort_value = a` will assign a to `sort_value` making it an `int` instead of adding it to a list.

You need to sort the list after you insert items to it, and you need to append to the list instead of assigning it

```
sort_value = []
chances = 1

while chances <= 5:
    a = int(input("Enter a number"))
    if a >= 0:
        sort_value.append(a)
        chances += 1

sort_value.sort()
print(sort_value)
```

Comment: I missed the append function instead I assigned a value so it didn't work well and now it executed without bugs. Thank You

Comment: @Guy I am here only for improving my knowledge and help others also,dont have time for stupid discussion.I have deleted my answer.